# WebDriver ignoring Xpath content after ::

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is my xpath:

```
(//td['displaytablecell']/span[text()='Name1']/../preceding-sibling::td[@class='ui-selection-column']/p-dtcheckbox/div/div[1]/input)[1]
```

Selenium WebDriver code is ignoring everything after :: in the above xpath.

Below is the error I get in selenium when I am above using xpath as a locator to identify element in a page.

```
Exception occured: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//td['displaytablecell']/span[text()='Name1']/../preceding-sibling because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//td['displaytablecell']/span[text()='Name1']/../preceding-sibling' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Any idea or suggestions on how to make webdriver take the whole xpath above?

Below is the `HTML` code:

```
<td class="ui-selection-column" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 38px; display: table-cell;">
<!--template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true" }-->
    <span class="ui-column-title"/>
    <p-dtcheckbox>
        <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        </div>
    </p-dtcheckbox>
</td>
<!--template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true" }-->
<td ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="display: table-cell;">
```

Below is the WebDriver Java Code:

```
    @Test
        public void test_byxpath(){

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("http://somesite.com");

            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[@style='display: table-cell;']/span[text()='Name1']/../preceding-sibling::td[@class='ui-selection-column']/p-dtcheckbox/div/div[2])[1]"));    
                System.out.println("Test7 number of elements: " + elements.size());
          element.click();
}
```

element is a checkbox which I am trying to check by applying method .click().

Below is the result I get in Eclipse:

```
Retrieving object of type 'xpath' and value '(//td[@style='display' from the object map
2017-01-25 16:52:09 -- INFO  automation.utilities.EventHandlerListener:102 - Trying to Find By.xpath: (//td[@style='display.
2017-01-25 16:52:10 -- INFO  automation.utilities.EventHandlerListener:98 - Exception occured: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//td[@style='display because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//td[@style='display' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
```

Comment: Are you sure that its not a typo: `p-dtcheckbox` ? Show `HTML` code for the same

Comment: @Andersson,  p-dtcheckbox doesn't have any typo. Looks like webdriver is not comfortable with :: that is present in my xpath.

Comment: If there is any Java code involved, please show that code here, together with a complete, minimal version of an input HTML document. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question but I'm pretty sure that the XPath expression is valid.

Comment: @Chuchoo It won't solve your current problem, but you're trying to click on list- you should use `findElement` instead of `findElements`

Comment: @Andersson, Yep I meant it to be findElement, not findElements. It is a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well if that doesn't work..then maybe try a different xpath:
`//td[span[text()='Name1']]/preceding-sibling::td[@class='ui-selection-column']//div[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-box')/]`